# apt-get dist-upgrade keeping back packets

Tags: ubuntu, apt

Running `apt-get dist-upgrade` on a Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS results in various packages being kept back:

```
root@localhost:/var/log/apt# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed libnss-mymachines libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libsystemd0 libudev1
  python3 python3-dev python3-distutils python3-gdbm python3-lib2to3 python3-minimal python3-tk python3.10 python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal systemd systemd-container systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd udev
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs libpcre2-8-0 python3-oauthlib
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 29 not upgraded.
5 standard security updates
Need to get 1,719 kB of archives.
After this operation, 3,072 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

The only method to effectively update such packages is to actively specify them on the command line:

```
root@localhost:/var/log/apt# apt-get dist-upgrade grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed libnss-mymachines libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libsystemd0 libudev1 python3 python3-dev python3-distutils python3-gdbm python3-lib2to3 python3-minimal python3-tk python3.10 python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal systemd systemd-container systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd udev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  systemd-hwe-hwdb
The following packages will be upgraded:
  bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs grub-efi-amd64 grub-efi-amd64-bin grub-efi-amd64-signed libnss-mymachines libnss-systemd libpam-systemd libpcre2-8-0 libpython3-dev libpython3-stdlib libpython3.10 libpython3.10-dev
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libsystemd0 libudev1 python3 python3-dev python3-distutils python3-gdbm python3-lib2to3 python3-minimal python3-oauthlib python3-tk python3.10 python3.10-dev python3.10-minimal systemd
  systemd-container systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd udev
34 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
5 standard security updates
Need to get 23.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 545 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] n
Abort.
```

It is my understanding that `apt dist-upgrade` should automatically update all packages. Why it is refusing doing that?

Answer (score 3):

After some debugging, I discovered it was due to phased updates not selecting my machine for applying the update. Disabling it via `-oAPT::Get::Always-Include-Phased-Updates=1` forces `apt-get dist-upgrade` to update anything.

Otherwise one can use `aptitude full-upgrade` to grab all updates, irrespective of their phased update state.

Comment: sudo apt full-upgrade still kept back the packages for me, but the first option worked.

Comment: @jmiserez you are right, it should be `aptitude full-upgrade` rather than `apt full-upgrade` (the former updates all packages, the latter respect the phased updates keeping back some packages).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the [Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get)

Differences between upgrade and dist-upgrade

### apt(-get) upgrade

> Used to install the newest versions of all packages currently
> installed on the system from the sources enumerated in
> /etc/apt/sources.list(5). Packages currently installed with new
> versions available are retrieved and upgraded; under no circumstances
> are currently installed packages removed, nor are packages that are
> not already installed retrieved and installed. New versions of
> currently installed packages that cannot be upgraded without changing
> the install status of another package will be left at their current
> version. An update must be performed first so that apt-get knows that
> new versions of packages are available.

### apt(-get) dist-upgrade

> In addition to performing the function of upgrade, this option also
> intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of
> packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict resolution system, and it
> will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the expense of
> less important ones, if necessary.

There is a Similar command for [apt-get](https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get) dist-upgrade, is [apt](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/apt.8.html) full-upgrade.

## Conclusion

- In easy words said, upgrade tries only conflict free packages that usually does not break the System in any kind.
- While dist-upgrade, as its word says, do an upgrade to the System. This action *can/could* break your system.

Comment: Thanks, but the question was not about the difference between upgrade and dist-upgrade. Rather, dist-upgrade behaved in an unexpected manner (at least to me).

Comment: it is not unusual that you may forced to run two times dist-upgrade. so in addition to the comment my answer is at the current stage fine ;) because "and it will attempt" means it tries at once but does not force it if its not possible

Comment: Running dist-upgrade two (or more) times in a row did not change anything: the following runs finished with no other updates being applied. The missed packages were due to phased updates - really.

Comment: I believe that this is a behavioral issue of Ubuntu, I found a [similar](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246962/what-apt-configuration-file-should-the-never-include-phased-updates-flag-be-pl) thread on the forum, so imho, I am right for native debian Derivate.